# Is innerHTML obtrusive JavaScript？

Tags: javascript

every one. I am now learning JavaScript in school. Our teacher suggests us not using obtrusive JavaScript. So I wonder whether the innerHTML obtrusive or not, thank you very much!

Comment: Rather use `textContent`, `innerHTML` just if necessary, but ive never heard *obstrusive javascript*...

Comment: InnerHTML is risky, because if you write user supplied text in this property it might turn unintentionally into HTML which can contain a cross site scripting (XSS) attack.

Answer (score 1):

No property is intrinsically part of obtrusive or unobtrusive JavaScript.

Whether or not a piece of JavaScript is unobtrusive or not depends on how it is designed to act [when the JS fails](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

This is obtrusive. If the JS doesn't work, then nothing happens.

```
<button type="button">
    Show the answer
</button>
<script>
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", show);
    function show() { document.body.innerHTML = "The answer"; }
</script>
```

This is unobtrusive. If the JS doesn't work, then the functionality of the JS is replaced by a server side fallback.

```
<a href="the-answer.html">
    Show the answer
</a>
<script>
    document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", show);
    function show(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        document.body.innerHTML = "The answer"; 
    }
</script>
```

This is unobtrusive (providing the functionality isn't critical). If the JS doesn't work, then the button isn't shown at all (so there is no broken button).

```
<script>
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.type = "button";
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener("click", show);
    function show() { 
        document.body.innerHTML = "The answer"; 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your teacher wants you to avoid, among other things, inline javascript.

As seen from Wikipedia's example of setting up a click handler, rather than an inline onclick function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're using it.

If, for example, you're using `innerHTML` to change the inner workings of some other element after the user clicks a link like this as part of an AJAX request:

`<a href="#" id="link1" onclick="document.getElementById('element').innerHTML=['page.html' contents]">View Page</a>`

...than yes, you're using it obtrusively.
If you were to do something like this:

`<a href="page.html" id="link1" class="ajax-link">View Page</a>`

and you had an external JavaScript file that handled the code which modifies `innerHTML` of another element, than you're using it unobtrusively.

The first example is **obtrusive** because the link will display the contents of 'page.html' for users with JavaScript enabled but not for those without.

The second example is **unobtrusive** because, with or without JavaScript, users will be see the contents of 'page.html'

Read more below:

> It boils down to this: your site, and it’s content, should still be accessible when JavaScript is unavailable – the only way to guarantee this 
>   is by employing Unobtrusive JavaScript techniques.

Source: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important